# Adding an extra level of parsing arrays in CodeIgniter parser class

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a navigation menu for my site and I use an array of links to build it with CodeIgniter's parser class.  My problem occurs when I want to add submenus that drop down.  The first level of variable pairs would be fine, except that it will always display a child ul element inside of the list items regardless if there are submenu links or not.

When I use this array, the ul elements for the submenus are set up properly, but none of the links for the submenus are parsing because it's missing that extra level.  How can I modify the CI parser class to parse an extra level of arrays?

This is my php array of the menu:

```
$data['navigation_links'] = array(
            array(
                'href' => site_url('home'),
                'title' => 'My Home Page',
                'target' => '',
                'text' => 'Home',
                'submenu' => array()
                ),
            array(
                'href' => site_url('blog'),
                'title' => 'My Blog',
                'target' => '',
                'text' => 'Blog',
                'submenu' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'href' => site_url('portfolio'),
                'title' => 'My Portfolio',
                'target' => '',
                'text' => 'Portfolio',
                'submenu' => array(
                    'submenu_links' => array(
                        array(
                            'sub_href' => site_url('portfolio/gallery'),
                            'sub_title' => 'Photography Gallery',
                            'sub_target' => '',
                            'sub_text' => 'Photography Gallery'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'sub_href' => site_url('portfolio/web-projects'),
                            'sub_title' => 'Web Projects',
                            'sub_target' => '',
                            'sub_text' => 'Web Projects'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'href' => site_url('services'),
                'title' => 'My Services',
                'target' => '',
                'text' => 'Services',
                'submenu' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'href' => site_url('resume'),
                'title' => 'My Resume',
                'target' => '',
                'text' => 'Resume',
                'submenu' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'href' => site_url('about'),
                'title' => 'About Me',
                'target' => '',
                'text' => 'About',
                'submenu' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'href' => site_url('contact'),
                'title' => 'Contact Me',
                'target' => '',
                'text' => 'Contact',
                'submenu' => array()
            )
        );
```

This is the menu section of the view file:

```
<nav class="container">
                        <ul>
                            {navigation_links}
                            <li><a href="{href}" title="{title}"{target}>{text}</a>
                                {submenu}
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                    {submenu_links}
                                    <li><a href="{sub_href}" title="{sub_title}"{sub_target}>{sub_text}</a></li>
                                    {/submenu_links}
                                </ul>{/submenu}</li>
                            {/navigation_links}
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

This is the HTML output:

```
<nav class="container">
                    <ul>

                        <li><a href="http://localhost/scotthlacey/index.php/home" title="My Home Page">Home</a>
                            </li>

                        <li><a href="http://localhost/scotthlacey/index.php/blog" title="My Blog">Blog</a>
                            </li>

                        <li><a href="http://localhost/scotthlacey/index.php/portfolio" title="My Portfolio">Portfolio</a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                {submenu_links}
                                <li><a href="{sub_href}" title="{sub_title}"{sub_target}>{sub_text}</a></li>
                                {/submenu_links}
                            </ul></li>

                        <li><a href="http://localhost/scotthlacey/index.php/services" title="My Services">Services</a>
                            </li>

                        <li><a href="http://localhost/scotthlacey/index.php/resume" title="My Resume">Resume</a>
                            </li>

                        <li><a href="http://localhost/scotthlacey/index.php/about" title="About Me">About</a>
                            </li>

                        <li><a href="http://localhost/scotthlacey/index.php/contact" title="Contact Me">Contact</a>
                            </li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap another level of array to submenu_links. Because your data (every array you want to iterate) have to be multi dimensional array to iterate by parser.

```
$data['navigation_links'] = array(
    array(
        'href' => site_url('home'),
        'title' => 'My Home Page',
        'target' => '',
        'text' => 'Home',
        'submenu' => array()
        ),
    array(
        'href' => site_url('blog'),
        'title' => 'My Blog',
        'target' => '',
        'text' => 'Blog',
        'submenu' => array()
    ),
    array(
        'href' => site_url('portfolio'),
        'title' => 'My Portfolio',
        'target' => '',
        'text' => 'Portfolio',
        'submenu' => array(
            array(
                'submenu_links' => array(
                    array(
                        'sub_href' => site_url('portfolio/gallery'),
                        'sub_title' => 'Photography Gallery',
                        'sub_target' => '',
                        'sub_text' => 'Photography Gallery'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'sub_href' => site_url('portfolio/web-projects'),
                        'sub_title' => 'Web Projects',
                        'sub_target' => '',
                        'sub_text' => 'Web Projects'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'href' => site_url('services'),
        'title' => 'My Services',
        'target' => '',
        'text' => 'Services',
        'submenu' => array()
    ),
    array(
        'href' => site_url('resume'),
        'title' => 'My Resume',
        'target' => '',
        'text' => 'Resume',
        'submenu' => array()
    ),
    array(
        'href' => site_url('about'),
        'title' => 'About Me',
        'target' => '',
        'text' => 'About',
        'submenu' => array()
    ),
    array(
        'href' => site_url('contact'),
        'title' => 'Contact Me',
        'target' => '',
        'text' => 'Contact',
        'submenu' => array()
    )
);
```

Hope it will be useful for you.